# Java - Recursively Permute List Without For Loops

Tags: java, list, for-loop, recursion

I want to create a different way of permuting a list like [apple, banana, orange] without using for loops recursively that will work for any size list and input etc. I already created one with using for loops, but I can't figure out myself without using for loops to solve the problem as this second part of solving a permutation without a for loops recursively is also going to be a question on our next exam (study guide I am reading) any idea how I would tackle this so I can see and understand how it works for the next exam question?

Comment: How about google "recursive", "permutation", "Java"?

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a loop by the following recursion:

1. do nothing for the empty list

otherwise

2. work on the first element
3. recurse, using the sublist that starts with the second element